# PancakeSwap V2 functions called automatically after adding myToken to a new pool: safebuy(), swapExactETHForTokens(), swapExactTokensForTokens()

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, bep20

I've created my own **BEP20 token** on BinanceSmartChain. After token creation with **myWallet** I added liquidity on **PancakeSwap** to a new liquidity pool (myToken, WBNB -> **myPool**).

There should be two transactions (token transfers) at the BSC explorer (***BscScan***):

1. initial token creation (0x00 -> myWallet)
2. function addLiquidityETH(myWallet, myToken, WBNB -> myPool)

But at the same time (exact same timestamp) there were more transactions:

3. myToken transaction (function **Safe Buy**) from myPool to a "*public*" PancakeSwap wallet that records a lot of transactions.
4. myToken transaction (function **Safe Buy**) from this public wallet back to myPool (amount: a small **fraction of the value before**)

A few seconds later there were more transactions I **never called** via function order PancakeSwap myself:

5.. **swapExactETHForTokens** called a few times **swapping myToken** and WBNB to **various wallets**.

Does anyone have any idea as to the purpose of the other transactions and why PancakeSwap is doing this?